# Php lazy regex does not behave lazy

Tags: php, regex

There is a url in several pages I need to remove.
It is implemented in several different ways, like a script source, used in a script as a variable, or a img src in a noscript tag.

I've written the following regex to deal with this:

```
/<[no]*script[\s\S]+?www.badurl.com[\s\S]+?<\/[no]*script>/i
```

The problem is, that it does not behave lazy all the time.

In the following example it should only select the last script block, but it does select both instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var stuff = {"foo":"bar"}foo.c(stuff,1);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var foo="http://www.badurl.com/cgi-bin/;[comment]";
document.write("<img src=\""+bar+"?r="+escape(document.referrer)+"&d="+(Math.random()*100000)+"\" width=\"1\" height=\"1\" alt=\"foobar\" />");
//-->
</script>
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lazy quantifiers do not work backwards, because the text is read left to right. The way this works is that the first `<script` is where regex starts matching your content, it CAN match because after any number of characters `badurl` link appears and the rest is working as you thought it would.

You are dealing with partial HTML/php parsing here, so it's not it's not really a piece of cake, and often not advised to be done. Redid the regex: `<(no)?script([\s\S](?!<\/(no)?script))+www.badurl.com[\s\S]*?<\/(no)?script>`, as seen https://regex101.com/r/uE9lZ8/3 . This should work though, the idea is that you match each character as long as there is no `</script>` tag following the character.

Comment: Thanks. That does explain a lot, I will test it in a moment. I expected that there would be a better solution than `[no]*script` to catch both `<script>` and `<noscript>`, but I'm not a regex pro and I use it maybe once in a year.

Comment: `[no]*` is a character class, which means that you can have `n` and `o` any number of time, i guess that it includes `no` too. (?:no)? would be what you are after.

Comment: Thank you very much! The last solution does work indeed. I've worked on this for hours. I've read that regex is not recommendet when working with html, but the people I'm trying to help with their site do have very chaotic code and I've had no success with the other methods I found.